# SQL MERGE with variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

How can I use the merge function with @variables in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 r2?

All of the examples that I have searched for online use tables to merge into tables. Is this possible with variables?

For Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateOrder
            @id int,
            @payment_date smalldatetime,
            @amount numeric(10,2)

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;



    MERGE order AS o
    USING @id, @payment_date, @amount
    ON @id = o.id
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                    UPDATE SET 
                               o.payment_date = @payment_date,
                               o.amount = @amount
                               o.last_updated_on = GETDATE()
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(o.id,o.payment_id,o.amount)
        VALUES(@id,@payment_id,@amount);
```

This does not work. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something like `using (select @id as id, @payment_date as payment_date, @amount as amount) myVals`? Then reference myVals.id, ect? I haven't tried this, just throwing it out there.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the `VALUES` clause to make a single row derived table then the rest is as usual.

```
MERGE order AS o
USING (VALUES (@id,
               @payment_date,
               @amount)) AS s(id, payment_date, amount)
ON s.id = o.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET o.payment_date = s.payment_date,
             o.amount = s.amount,
             o.last_updated_on = GETDATE()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(o.id,
         o.payment_id,
         o.amount)
  VALUES(s.id,
         s.payment_id,
         s.amount);
```

You might want to read [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) as well though.

Comment: I was looking for this article of Aaron to explain OP why I would not use Merge statement :)

Comment: Awesome this works, however I will take your recommendation to avoid merge. I will be using @M.Ali's suggestion. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Would you still avoid Merge?

Comment: @johnny - No, I'd use it with caution though. It has some useful functionality that other statements can't reproduce. Such as being able to reference the source table in the `OUTPUT` clause. I haven't personally been hit by any of the bugs in production. Execution plan performance can sometimes be a problem with `MERGE`. Also to be threadsafe this answer should use the `HOLDLOCK` hint to guarantee no duplicates inserted under load

Answer (score 7):

Or you can simply check for existence of record and then do the update/insert

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [order] WHERE ID = @id)
 BEGIN
     UPDATE [order]
      SET payment_date = @payment_date,
          amount       = @amount,
          last_updated_on = GETDATE()
     WHERE ID = @id
 END

ELSE 

 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [order](id,payment_id,amount)
   VALUES(@id,@payment_id,@amount)
 END
```

Comment: This can cause race conditions: https://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/